# Convert InputStream to Flux<MyClass>

Tags: spring-webflux, inputstream, project-reactor

We are given an `InputStream` which represents the response body of a `text/event-stream` HTTP response. The stream emits events periodically, every few seconds.

Now we need to find a way to convert this `InputStream` into `Flux<MyClass>`. The goal is to use a `StepVerifier` on that stream, to check that each object has the expected structure, and to close the stream in the end.

How could this be done?